# BxSlider white space

Tags: border, margin, bxslider

I am new to html/css/javascript and am trying to add an image slider using BxSlider to my website. I am having an issue when the slider expands to a certain size it starts adding a white edge. Is this because the images have reached their maximum width? Or do I need to change something in the code?

My images and slider are in a div with id of wrapper. The css is:

```
#wrapper {
    max-width: 70%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 0 %;
    padding-top: 4%;

}
```

and have css for img as

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    padding: none;
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Although you have not included enough information to simply answer yes/no to your question (ie. dimensions of the source images and the containing element), I would say that you are right.

A quick test on bxSlider homepage - increasing the width of div.home-slider-wrapper above 1000px (which is width of their source images) caused a white border on the right. [See annotated screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50Zdj.png).

Try changing CSS for the images from `max-width: 100%` to `width: 100%` if it works for you (removes the white border at the cost of proportional stretching the images).